# how to pass checkbox value from view to controller in laravel while clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

Here is my code:
  View

```
    <label>
<input class="i-check" name="amenity[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$amn->ht_amenity_id}}" />{{$amn->ht_amenity_name}}
     </label>
```

Controller

```
$purp = $_POST['amenity'];
    print_r($purp);
```

Here (In controller), I'm just trying to print the value

Please Some one help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX

in View:

```
$(selector).change(function()
{
    if($(selector).is(':checked'))
        checked = 'checked';
    else
        checked = 'unchecked';
    $.post('The page u want', checked:checked, function(data){});
});
```

in Controller:

The code that you mentioned:

```
$purp = $_POST['checked'];
    print_r($purp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Arya Basiri :) But I'm just using        $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){
         var value_to_send = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
             return this.value;
         }).get().join(', '));

         $.get('route_to_your_action', {value_name: value_to_send},function(data)           {
             //data contain response from controller action
         })
     });
   });    To pass values to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You use Laravel, so you should do it the right way by using Laravel Collective with it's Form::model and Form::open constructions:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons

Laravel will pass the data to `store()` or `update()` method inside controller for you. Then you can use it with something like: `$request->get('name')`

Also, learn about RESTful controllers, it's the easiest way to work with forms:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Thank You so much Alexey Mezenin :)

Comment: @SuganyaRajsekar, if my answer was helful, please upvote and choose it as best answer.